# Git - Keeping protected feature branch in sync with master

Tags: git, github, version-control

My team works with feature branches that get branched out of master at some point

```
# make sure the local version of master is up to date
git checkout master
git fetch origin 
git reset --hard origin/master

# create a new branch
git checkout -b feature/name
```

These feature branches can live for a few months while we develop the new feature, but master also changes in that timespan as we address bugs or other feature branches get merged.

We mostly follow the process described in [feature-branch-workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow). Github also has good documentation [about-protected-branches](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches).

Now, the issue is that the team decided to protect the feature branch (including administrators), leaving us with a few options when syncing `master` and `feature/name`:

1. temporarily remove the branch protection rules so we can update `feature/name` with `master`

   Pros: easier option (usually just use the Github UI to sync branch). Good to solve small conflicts -- `git checkout feature/name`; `git merge master`; solve conflicts, commit, and `git push`

   Cons: Risk of someone pushing to an unprotected branch (even if temporarily); merge conflict errors and code that is not peer-reviewed
2. create a PR to the feature branch that includes the changes from master

   Pros: all code gets reviewed

   Cons: time-consuming; PRs usually get very big
3. a mix of both depending on the conflicts to solve

   Pros: Use approach 1 for small conflicts (conflicts in changelog for instance) and use approach 2 for bigger conflicts

   Cons: Gray-zone of what is a small or big conflict. Same cons as option 1

I wonder how can this process be improved. Feature branches need at least two approvals to merge to master. Would it be safe to remove administrators from the branch rules? Are PRs, even if big, the way to go? What are the best practices?

Comment: Minor thought: I'm not sure this particular sentence is relevant: "Feature branches need at least two approvals to merge to master." Because this question is about merging `master` into `feature/name`, not the other way around. When you make `feature/name` protected, I assume you can decide whether you still want those 2 approvals required for that branch, or not.

Comment: I thought it is relevant in the sense that even if there are some errors in the branch from approach #1, these errors will likely be caught by one of the two reviewers

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand it, your best option is #2: Always require a PR into the protected feature branch. This means you may need to sometimes include the updated `master` in a PR into the protected feature branch.

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Periodically create a separate PR of `master` into `feature/name` (which may require a separate temp branch if there are conflicts).
2. Have one of the feature branches getting PR'd into `feature/name` include the latest `master` in their branch.

Note the "con" you present for this option may not be a big deal:

> time-consuming; PRs usually get very big

Regardless of whether you use a PR or just push out the merge, the conflicts still have to be resolved, and the merge still needs to be reviewed and tested. The overhead of the PR (compared to pushing without a PR) for a large change should generally be similar to that of a PR for a one-line change, except perhaps additional required sign-offs and/or builds; but those shouldn't increase "person-time" that much.

Note there's another advantage of always requiring a PR to get code into a protected feature branch, without exceptions. When it comes time to merge the protected feature branch back into `master`, the reviewers will know that *every* change on the feature branch has already been code reviewed. That way the reviewers can focus on the changes as a result of the merge, rather than also having to do an in-depth review of every individual change for functionality, style, etc.

**Tip**: I tell developers to generally avoid ever checking out `master` and to delete their local copy of it, because you almost never actually need it. Nearly every command you'd run with `master` can be substituted with `origin/master` instead. You can simplify the 4 commands you use to create a feature branch to these 2 commands instead:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b feature/name origin/master --no-track
```

The end result is identical but you never have to bother checking out `master`, and you also won't ever accidentally use an outdated copy of your local `master`.